# UCanAccess relative path to Access database file

Tags: java, database, eclipse, path, ucanaccess

I have written a simple program for myself which works with an Access database file.
I used the absolute path to connect to the db:

```
String path = "jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Development/20_Eclipse/Budget/data/Budget.accdb";
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path);
```

When I use the runnable jar somewhere else this path (understandably) doesn't work. So I tried relative paths but they didn't work either.

Then I tried to build the path using

```
String path = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + helper.programmPathForDB() + "/data/Budget.accdb";
```

where `helper.programPathForDB()` does this:

```
public String programmPathForDB()
{
    String tempPath = this.getClass().getResource( "." ).toString();
    String path = tempPath.substring(6, (tempPath.length()-12));

    return path;
}
```

This works ONLY when I start the program through my IDE (Eclipse). When I start the jar somewhere else it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: is the location relation to the jar or where the application is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help of Gord Thompson above i solved it with deploying the DB under APPDATA And using the Envirement Variable + my Project path:

```
String path = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + System.getenv("APPDATA") + "/Budget/data/Budget.accdb";
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have the database file in a folder that is relative to (for example, a subfolder of) the location of the JAR file. If so, then

[Get location of JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15359702/2144390)

offers some suggestions on how to determine location of the JAR file.

However, you should bear in mind that it might not be such a good idea to put the database file there. Depending on how the application is deployed, such a location may deny write access to users without elevated privileges (e.g., `%ProgramFiles%` under Windows). Also, moving the JAR file without also moving the database file could break your application.

All modern operating systems provide well-known and discoverable locations where applications can safely put "stuff" that is not an integral part of the (executable) application itself. For example, Windows offers `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` for user-specific locations, along with `%PUBLIC%` for resources that need to be shared among all users. You should consider using (a subfolder of) one of those locations for your database file.

Comment: thank u so much, i will take a look into ur link tomorrow. I got some problems installing my project on some devices. With ur explanation about the elevated privileges it makes sense, cause i treied to install all inclusive db to ProgramFiles. When i have the DB under APPData The Path to it will be the same on every windows pc or?

Comment: The absolute path might not be the same on every machine, but every machine will have an environment variable that can be used to determine the actual path. That's what I meant when I used the term "discoverable" above.

Answer (score 1):

The UCanAccess connection URL must always begin with jdbc:ucanaccess://, followed by the path to the database file.

For a relative path (e.g., src/main/resources/testDB.accdb) that would be

jdbc:ucanaccess://src/main/resources/testDB.accdb